# Xamarin bluetooth won't receive all bytes

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, bluetooth

I tried to receive data from the windows program Termite on my Xamarin program through bluetooth. This is the code I used for receiving data:

```
        public async Task BeginListenForData()
    {
        try
        {
            inStream = btSocket.InputStream;
            streamReader = new StreamReader(inStream);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        char[] buffer = new char[256];
        int bytes;
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((bytes = await streamReader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        buffer = new Char[(int)streamReader.BaseStream.Length];
                        streamReader.Read(buffer, 0, (int)streamReader.BaseStream.Length);

                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(new String(buffer));

                            string eindtekst = new string(buffer, 0, bytes);
                            streamReader.DiscardBufferedData();

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Java.IO.IOException)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }).ConfigureAwait(false) ;
            return;
        }
```

But when I used breakpoint it receives my message most of the time in two parts. For example the string "Received", it received first the "R" and than the rest of the string "eceived". Is there a way to receive the message as one part?

This code part: `bytes = await streamReader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length` is where `bytes` is first 1 and than 7 with the example of the string "Received".

Comment: this is normal behavior for this sort of buffered communication.  It's your job as the programmer to deal with it

Comment: You can increase your buffer size, just like `char[] buffer = new char[1024];`

Comment: But if I send "Received" it should fit inside a char [] buffer = new char [10]; at most with /n. So theoretically it wouldn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within an other question I posted about an other problem I solved this problem with it. I posted my answer on the other page, so I will leave a link to the other page about how to receive data within Xamarin with bluetooth.

[How to receive data with bluetooth in xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60928317/async-task-wont-finish-method-after-while-loop-false/60947171#60947171)

Thanks for all help given