# Async task won't finish method after while loop == false

Tags: c#, xamarin

Perhaps a strange question, but I can't seem to figure it out. I am receiving data from a bluetoothstream, after I have read all the incoming data within a while loop I would like to compare this message. But what happens is that it just won't finish the rest of the code. This is the code as following:

```
 public void beginListenForData()
    {
        try
        {
            inStream = btSocket.InputStream;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Task.Run(async() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    bytes = await inStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    while (bytes != 0)
                    {
                        eindtekst = String.Concat(eindtekst, Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
                        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        bytes = await inStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    }

                    if (eindtekst == "D0O")
                    {
                        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send((IBluetoothService)this, "redButtonClicked");
                        eindtekst = "";
                        inStream.Flush();
                        inStream.Dispose();
                        inStream.Close();
                    }
                    else if (eindtekst == "StopTijd")
                    {
                        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send((IBluetoothService)this, "Win");
                        eindtekst = "";
                        inStream.Flush();
                        inStream.Dispose();
                        inStream.Close();
                    }

                    if (bytes == 0)
                    {
                        eindtekst = "";
                        inStream.Flush();
                        inStream.Dispose();
                        inStream.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fout bij het ontvangen " + e.Message);
                break;
                }
            }
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return;
    }
```

What I would expect is that after while == 0 it would stop within this while loop and finish the rest of the code. But this does not seems to happen, it won't finish the code it goes back to the calling method without any error or so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the stream actually being closed? there's a huge difference between "no more data is currently available" vs "no more data is available **and the input stream is marked as closed**" - only the latter returns 0; the former will await forever (unless there is a timeout specified) - or rather: it will await until *either* at least one byte is available, or it *becomes* closed

Comment: The stream is not closed yet, but my thought process was that if there isn't data in the stream then is should be closed. But it should be closed when bytes == 0. But when I tried that as well with if(bytes == 0) than close it won't ever get in the if statement

Comment: **1.** Does `while (bytes != 0)` loop end? **2.** Try to add `catch (Exception e)` to `try` block? May be an exception other than `IOException` is thrown and therefore code after `while (bytes != 0)` loop is not executed.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong. I don’t think `while (bytes != 0)` is correct. The condition to terminate the loop should be `bytes < buffer.Length`?

Comment: 1. No it does not end 2. I Will try to change the exception type Will update if I know more. Buffer.length = 1024 and I am using string of max 8 that should not be the problem. The reason why I use while (bytes!=0) is  bcs when instream.readasync() == 0 no data is available so, loop through instream amd place IT info buffer while instream != 0 (no data)

Comment: Update on the previous answer, it does not give an exception back with catch(Exception e). Any other possibilities?

Comment: Is it because you repeatedly nested while(true) and called the `bytes = await inStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`  when you loop  `inStream.ReadAsync  `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for any one who has problems with bluetooth within xamarin I just found the answer. This is just a "simple" method for reading data from an other device like an Arduino, pic microcontroller, Raspberry pi, etc. There is I think enough information about writing data so that should not be the problem. But herby my answer on receiving data from an other device.

```
 public void beginListenForData()
    {
        try
        {
            inStream = btSocket.InputStream;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (inStream.IsDataAvailable() == true)
                    {
                        bytes = await inStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        eindtekst = String.Concat(eindtekst, Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
                        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        if (eindtekst == "Received")
                        {
                            Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<IBluetoothService, bool>(this, "Received", true);
                        }
                        else if (eindtekst == "D0O")
                        {
                            Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send((IBluetoothService)this, "redButtonClicked");
                        }
                        else if (eindtekst == "StopTijd")
                        {
                            Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send((IBluetoothService)this, "Win");
                        }
                        eindtekst = "";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fout bij het ontvangen " + e.Message);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return;
    }
```

I hope this will help some one in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you repeatedly nested while(true) and called the `bytes = await inStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`  when you loop `inStream.ReadAsync`?

I didn't test it to see if it worked. Your looping method doesn't look very clear，maybe you could try below:

```
 Task.Run(async() =>
    {        
         int bytes = 0;
           try
            {

                while (bytes =await inStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
                {
                    eindtekst = String.Concat(eindtekst, Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
                    Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                }

                if (eindtekst == "D0O")
                {
                    Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send((IBluetoothService)this, "redButtonClicked");
                    eindtekst = "";
                    inStream.Flush();
                    inStream.Dispose();
                    inStream.Close();
                }
                else if (eindtekst == "StopTijd")
                {
                    Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send((IBluetoothService)this, "Win");
                    eindtekst = "";
                    inStream.Flush();
                    inStream.Dispose();
                    inStream.Close();
                }

                if (bytes == 0)
                {
                    eindtekst = "";
                    inStream.Flush();
                    inStream.Dispose();
                    inStream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fout bij het ontvangen " + e.Message);
            break;
            }
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sad enough this does not seems to work. But I will post my answer how just solved it soo. Thanks for the effort